# Dr Memory Leak - C - malloc 3d array

Tags: c, memory-leaks, dr-memory

I am using Dr. Memory to debug legacy code that is crashing in certain conditions.

Dr. Memory says there is a memory leak during allocation:

```
float   ***in_vol=NULL;
in_vol=(float ***) malloc(inimsize[12]*sizeof(float **)); // here **
                   // inimsize is array of ints
 for (i0=0;i0<inimsize[12];i0++) {
   in_vol[i0] =(float **) malloc(inimsize[0]*sizeof(float *));

   for (i1=0;i1<inimsize[0];i1++)  {
      in_vol[i0][i1]=(float *) malloc(inimsize[1]*sizeof(float ));
   }
 }
```

The memory is later freed:

```
for (i0=0;i0<in_header[0][12];i0++) {
  for (i1=0;i1<in_header[0][0];i1++)  {
    free( (float*) *(*(in_vol+i0)+i1) );

  }
    free( (float*)  *(in_vol+i0));
}

free( (float*)in_vol); 
in_vol=NULL;
```

I do not see the problem, however, I am running out of memory during some tests.

**Are the allocation and freeing correct?**

Comment: it doesn't answer the question, but as you are writing C you do not need to cast the result of malloc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Your allocation count is `inimsize[12]` but your free count is `in_header`. Can you post more code to show how these are set up. If it were me, I'd be using the same limits on all `for` loops

Comment: You use `inimsize` when allocating and `in_header` when freeing. There's nothing to show that those sizes are the same, so a leak or memory abuse is certainly possible.

Comment: in_header is a copy of inimsize, so it appears to be the same.

    for (i=0;i<20;i++)
       in_header[njj][i] = inimsize[i];
     }

I will keep checking a provide a helpful answer when I can

Comment: Being a 3-star C programmer is not a compliment! It is always almost a signal of bad inderface design. And read [ask]. We need a [mcve].

Comment: If your diagnostic tool is telling you there's something wrong, there's likely something wrong. What the diagnostic tool can't see is the language you are using. If it could, it'd be quite verbose indeed! An array is a contiguous, *single allocation*. What you're creating is not a *3-dimensional array* but a *tree*.